# How can handle UI.text object in unity by using method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'd like to update UI.text by using UIManager methods.

This is UIManager script.

```
public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static UIManager m_instance;
    public static UIManager instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
                m_instance = FindObjectOfType<UIManager>();
            return m_instance;
        }
    }

    public void UpdatePlayerInfo(ref Text refText, string playerID, long money)
    {
        refText.text = "ID: " + playerID + "\n" + "money: " + money;
        refText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
```

And I called UIManager method in Player script, like following code.

```
/* player script */
public bool Batting(int batIndex)
    {
        long toBat;

        ...
        money -= toBat;
        betMoney += toBat;
        
        // Here!
        UIManager.instance.UpdatePlayerBat(ref handText, betMoney);
        UIManager.instance.UpdatePlayerInfo(ref playerInfoText, playerName, money);
        return (true);
    }
```

But, it couldn't be updated.
I guess, it is a problem associate with Text object when using it parameter.
I already tried Text object with "ref" keyword and without "ref" keyword. But I don't know why...
Can't I use Text object in parameter ?
Or, is there any way that I can handle Text object by using method ?

Thank you !

Comment: I do not understand the ref concept.If you have removed ref and tried then I have got some questions. Which text are you trying to update here?  refText.text field should be declared here inside UIManager script right? Instead you are updating the value which is passed.
Inside UIManger a field should be there ............
private Text updateText;
updateText.text = "ID: " + playerID + "\n" + "money: " + money;

Answer (score 0):

Omg, it was my fault.
The code is not need "ref" keyword.

But I forgot add UIManager object in hierarchy.
The function is working well when I add UIManager object in gameobject !!